# Android Studio only shows Gradle files in Project and Android in the "Project" side menu, all other folders have nothing to show

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I want to know how to make my project files appear in the "Project" side menu pictured [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrqsW.png) ([Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejZCk.png) is the Android folder which I mentioned also actually had content).

I can find the files in the [file explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5mT6.png). I'll note that all that I've done is create this project (and a couple others to see if it just didn't set-up right), so I haven't made any changes in Android Studio or the code in the project.

I can reach the files clicking the [top row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtdnO.png), but this takes time and since this is one of my first android projects I can't find my way around that well - So having all files visible is pretty much a must.

All of the tutorials and explanations of [how to use Android Studio](https://www.androidauthority.com/android-studio-tutorial-beginners-637572/) already have the files visible there. I would like some help so I can actually start coding :) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, the reason why files disappears is either you had a gradle sync problem when importing the project OR there is a problem with your settings.gradle who's in charge to tell AS which module to load for the project. (usually simply `include ':app'` on new projects).

Try `File / Sync Project with Gradle Files`

You can also try to simply Close the project and reopening it (File / Close Project)
If this does not work, you should try and post your `app/build.gradle` file to help further.

Comment: Thanks for the help! They appeared after I synced with both Gradle Files and File System.

Answer (score 5):

I delete .idea and .gradle folders and restart android studio.

this resolve my issue.

thanks.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the tip! In my case I just needed to remove the .idea folder :-)