# Android package view is gone after update to Android Studio 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio

When installing the latest Android Studio 4.1, my Android View in the project only shows the gradle files and no longer the modules and files. Is there a way to fix this issue?

[image: Current Android View]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio only shows Gradle files in Project and Android in the "Project" side menu, all other folders have nothing to show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51839319/android-studio-only-shows-gradle-files-in-project-and-android-in-the-project-s)

Comment: unfortunatly not, Synching didn't do anything. I had to delete the .IDEA folder

Comment: Worked for me when deleting .idea folder then invalidate/restart

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

1. Delete `.idea/modules.xml`
2. File > Sync Project with Gradle Files